# Ubuntu 12.10, where is terminal?

Tags: ati, 64-bit

Is a AMD 64 Athlon processor support by Ubuntu 12.10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the AMD Athlon 64 is supported.

You can get terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>